# Combine like primary keys in MySQL JOIN result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that is returning results like so:

```
Table Units  Table Payments
ID          |  Payment
1003        |  300.00
1003        |  100.00
1004        |  350.00
1005        |  200.00
```

How can I structure the query such that it combines the same IDs like so:

```
ID      |  Payment
1003    |  400.00
1004    |  350.00
1005    |  200.00
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT u.id, p.amt FROM units u JOIN payments p ON u.id = p.unit
```

---

I have tried to `SUM()` the `amt` field but it only returns one result like so:

```
ID      |  Payment
1003    |  950.00
```

Comment: the concept you are missing is: if aggregate function not applied with "group by" clause then function will be applied on all rows in output.

Comment: Someone upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, sum(p.amt) as payment
FROM units u inner JOIN payments p ON u.id = p.unit
group by u.id
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c54c6e/1)**

Comment: @user2690363 no you are missing "group by"

Comment: Sorry, I saw `GROUP BY` as `ORDER BY` in your post. Thank you. That does work!